# How can I use AppInsights with Angular?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-application-insights, appinsights

I am trying to use AppInsights with Angular:

```
import { AppInsights } from 'applicationinsights-js';

....

if (!AppInsights.config) {
    var config: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.IConfig = {
        instrumentationKey: environment.appInsightsInstrumentationKey
    };

    AppInsights.downloadAndSetup(config);
}

// code for logging exception:
AppInsights.trackException(errorMessage, "GlobalErrorHandler", {
    UserName: userName,
    ViewName: url
}, { }, AI.SeverityLevel.Error);

// code for logging page views
AppInsights.trackPageView(name, url, {
    UserName: userName,
    ViewName: url
}, { });
```

I ran into two issues with this code:

1. an exception is not tracked at all in app insights using this code, and
2. a page view is tracked, but it does not contain the custom properties.

I tried to look into the source code of the module for AppInsights (applicationinsights-js), but could not find a solution.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Hello Martin, if the post is helpful, could you accept it as answer? If you still have more issues, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I tried to implement changes according to your answer, but still the issues described in the question persist. I tried out the other library `applicationinsights-web`, and it behaves the same way as the library `applicationinsights-js`. I a bit resigned and postponed the solution.

Answer (score 2):

> an exception is not tracked at all in app insights using this code

Please check if [disableExceptionTracking](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#configuration) is set to true or false.

> a page view is tracked, but it does not contain the custom properties

you should try to add [properties](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#sending-telemetry-to-the-azure-portal) like below:

```
AppInsights.trackPageView(name, url, properties:{
    UserName: userName,
    ViewName: url
}, { });
```

And also please try to use [@microsoft/applicationinsights-web](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#getting-started) packages.